# Use .Net Framework dll (v4.7.2) in .Net Core project

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, azure-functions, .net-4.7.2

The .Net Framework dll which I am using gets included in the .Net core project(Azure Functions v2) perfectly fine but at runtime it gives error "

> System.Runtime.Caching: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager".

I tried including it via Nuget. Still not working. The external dll which I am trying to use which is in .Net Framework seems to use Configuration Manager. Is there any workaround to make it work?

Tried using .Net Standard and included the Framwork dll, still getting the same error

Comment: Framework and core a completely incompatible. Use .net standard if you need to share an assembly between them

Comment: Tried using .Net Standard. Same error is coming there as well.

Comment: Can you show the .csproj file of your project? This error should comes from the conflict between function v2 and ConfigurationManager.

Answer (score 0):

Did you reference **`System.Configuration`** or **`System`** in your application?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using some packages based on .NetFramework? The problem should comes from they based on ConfigurationManager. Azure function v2 and later version didn't support ConfigurationManager any more. If you want to use those package, you can use azure function v1 instead of function v2.

Or you can show the .csproj file in your question. Those package maybe too old and have another version that works on .Net Core.